# How do you re use a field in SAS in proc sql?

Tags: sas

If have the data step:

```
data myRegions;
set myRegions;
ext_price = price * qty;
mix = weighted_calc * ext_price;
run;
```

I wan to do this on SQL as I want to use some groupings and subqueries
but do I hace t make   `price * qty` operation everytime I want to use that value?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [calculated](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002294533.htm) , from the docs:

> CALCULATED enables you to use the results of an expression in the same
>   SELECT clause or in the WHERE clause.  It is valid only when used to
>   refer to columns that are calculated in the immediate query
>   expression.

Here is an example:

```
proc sql;    
create table myRegions as
Select a.*,  
        (price * qty) as ext_price ,
        (weighted_calc * calculated ext_price ) as mix
from     myRegions;
quit;
```